# Global variable

Tags: swiftui, global-variables

Is there any way I can make it so I can use the variable "bggg"? Im trying to make a api call and then use the data to change the view but I cannot figure out how to access the variables. Its saying that it cannot find bggg in its scope.

```
public struct RootView: View {
    
     public init() {Task {
         let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string:"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=32&lon=-94&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=bf1daa8bf4997bc299d459c8db985f8f")!)
         let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
         var bggg = decodedResponse.current.weather.description
     }}
    
     var body: some View {
         Text("\(bggg)")
         Color.red
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Combine: set a publisher which means a property that sends data, then set another property as subscriber(this property will listen to the publisher) if any changes will happen immediately the subscriber will be notified

**1. Set the publisher**

```
class DownloadWithCombineViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bggg: String = ""
    public init() {Task {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string:"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=32&lon=-94&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=bf1daa8bf4997bc299d459c8db985f8f")!)
        let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
        var bggg = decodedResponse.current.weather.description
    }
}
```

**2. set the subscriber (ObservedObject)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var value = DownloadWithCombineViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value.bggg)")
        Color.red
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI view state is managed by various property wrappers: [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/), [`@StateObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/), [`@Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/), [`@EnvironmentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject/), etc. These will be covered in most SwiftUI tutorials, but in this case if you want to keep the State local to the View, you might implement it like this:

```swift
public struct RootView : View {
    @State private var bggg: String = "Loading…"

     public var body: some View {
         Text("\(bggg)")
             .task {
                 do {
                     let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string:"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=32&lon=-94&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=bf1daa8bf4997bc299d459c8db985f8f")!)
                     let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
                     self.bggg = decodedResponse.current.weather.description
                 } catch {
                     self.bggg = "Error: \(error)"
                 }
             }
     }
}
```